# How do I click this Bootstrap button in Capybara?

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, rspec, capybara

How do I click on this button in Capybara?

[image: Imgur]

#### HTML

```
<div class="btn btn-primary">
    <a href="/carts/7/addresses/new"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      Add an address
    </a>
</div>
```

I tried

```
click_button "Add an Address"
click_button /Add an Address/
click 'Add an Address'
click_link 'Add an Address'
```

Yet they all say `Capybara::ElementNotFound`, except for click, which says `NoMethodError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote it from lower letter in html code, just change to Capital: `Add an address` -> `Add an Address`:

```
<a href="/carts/7/addresses/new"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  Add an address
         ^
</a>
```

Comment: You were right. I could have sworn that I matched the case.